# Same java code in different projects, different results

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, twitter4j

I have been messing around with twitter4j, and have a weird error. I have been messing around with it in its own project, using basically this:

https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/stream/PrintSampleStream.java

and it works exactly as expected.

When I move this package (twitter.PrintSampleStream.java) to a larger project (so now it is under src/twitter.PrintSampleStream.java) the code does not work; all that is displayed on console is the following:

```
Nov 30, 2013 12:42:31 PM twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl info
INFO: Establishing connection.
Nov 30, 2013 12:42:31 PM twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl info
INFO: Connection established.
Nov 30, 2013 12:42:31 PM twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl info
INFO: Receiving status stream.
```

After that last line nothing happens (doesn't terminate, doesn't stream anything, etc.)

When I run this exact same code on my original project, I have the stream output as expected, and am able to get the tweets.

What could be causing this issue? I have tried cleaning, etc. but this maintains. This is some weird configuration issue I cannot figure out. Thanks

Comment: Maybe there is no tweet released obeying your criteria.